# Why doesn't cmd show my d?

Tags: cmd.exe

Put this into a .cmd (or .bat) file and run it from inside a cmd.exe window:

```
for /d %%x in (a) do @echo %%x
```

Because I did not put `@echo off` on top as usual, this line is logged (before echoing the `a`):

> for / %x in (a) do @echo %x

I understand why the double `%`s are turned into single ones. But where did the `d` go in `/d`? This confused me a lot!

Comment: See [parsing - How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts). It gets removed in step 2 before the line is printed in step 3. No idea why other than it's no longer needed for further processing.

Comment: "All FOR options are fully parsed in phase 2" explains nothing IMHO...